# Model class not found in not found in C:\wamp\www\redirect\system\core\Loader.php on line 303

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting error when calling the model from controller.
Error:-  SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Redirection_model' not found in C:\wamp\www\redirect\system\core\Loader.php on line 30
My controller redirection.php

```
<?php 

 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class redirection extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //$this->layout->setLayout('layouts/main'); 
}

public function redirection_url()
{       
            if($_GET){
                $get_array = $_GET;
                $targetId = $get_array['tagid'];
                $this->load->model('redirection_model', 'redirection');
                $dynamicurl = $this->redirection->getDynamicUrl($targetId);
                if($dynamicurl){
                     $url=$dynamicurl['url'];
                     redirect($url,'refresh');
                }
                else{
                    echo "Invalid Request";
                }

            }
            else{
                echo "please pass the tagid";
               // $this->layout->view('redirection/redirection_url');

            }

    }
```

}

redirection_model.php

```
  <?

    class redirection_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function getDynamicUrl($targetId){
    $dynamicUrl= array();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('dynamic_url', array('tagid' => $targetId))->row();
    if($query){
        $dynamicUrl['url'] = $query->url;
        $dynamicUrl['userid'] = $query->userid;
                    return $dynamicUrl;
    }
            else{
                return false;
            }

}


   }

 ?>
```

Comment: While extending Class names must start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I tried your solution sir, but dint able to fix the error

Comment: Then update your code and also just curious: your model file is with in model directory. yes? not inside other folders?

Comment: My Model file is in model directory only.

Answer (score 0):

you have not linked your view in controller, insert it.
And Also check you route file which is in your config folder, there you have to make entry for for your functions and route for view.